# Include a header file while a program runs

Tags: c++, dynamic

I'm writing a C++ server for an autonomous vehicle. The vehicle has a camera on it and many image processing algorithms to help it understand its surrounding.

The server needs to be able to receive an image processing algorithm(a cpp file and a header file) from a client ,and to run this algorithm.

My question is, how can a program include a header file while running(is it even possible)?

Comment: i think you need to use dynamic library. I don't think it is possible to compile code if there are unresolved symbols.

Comment: You may want to look at using OpenCL or some such, but if you are looking to really have native code that interfaces with your existing app, then a shared library (DLL) plugin would be the traditional solution. There are lots of examples of that around.

Comment: This seems promising... http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot include a header file while a program is running. You are describing a plug-in architecture. C++ provides no native support.

If you really want to do this, you have a lot of work in front of you. You have to devise (or find) a suitable plug-in architecture that allows on-the-fly loading. You have to implement the algorithms you need in that architecture. You have to devise a mechanism to identify required algorithms and load them.

Surely it would be better to start with a static architecture and pre-load every algorithm you can think of before going down this route?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not up to me to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents..

1) Have a tiny c/c++ compiler in hand [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler].
2) Once you recieve the source file, invoke the compiler progmatically and build the objects.
3) Then load those object dynamically.